# How can I get the _id value of a user stored in a User schema?

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I'm working on a Facebook clone using Express/MongoDB/ejs and I'm setting up friend requests. Each user is stored in a User schema and is assigned their own `id` value. I know how to get my own id but I can't seem to figure out how to get the id of the person I'm sending a friend request to. Each user is given their own username. Each route is based on the username value so if I were to go to `/users/dagger` I would be at username `Dagger`'s profile. If I were to go to `/users/pepper` I would be at `Pepper`'s profile.

User schema.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstname: String,
  lastname: String,
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, "can't be blank"],
    match: [/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, "is invalid"],
    index: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true,
    required: [true, "can't be blank"],
    match: [/\S+@\S+\.\S+/, "is invalid"],
    index: true,
  },
  password: String,
  email: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  friends: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User",
    },
  ],
});
```

User route. This is how I'm getting my own id

```
router.get("/:user", async function (req, res, next) {
  const user = req.user.username;
  const id = req.user.id;
  Status.find({}, "content author createdAt")
    .sort({ title: 1 })
    .exec(function (err, list_status) {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      res.render("profile", {
        status_list: list_status,
        user: user,
        id: id,
      });
    });
});
```

Here is my button that sends a friend request. I need the `receiver` value to be the id of the person I'm sending the request to.

```
<form action="/friend-requests" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="receiver" value="?" />
  <input type="hidden" name="sender" value="<%= user._id %>" />
  <button type="submit">Send Friend Request</button>
</form>
```

And here is my code to send the friend request.

```
router.post("/friend-requests", (req, res) => {
  const { sender, receiver } = req.body;

  // Create a new FriendRequest instance
  const newRequest = new FriendRequest({
    sender,
    receiver,
  });

  // Save the friend request to the database
  newRequest
    .save()
    .then(() => {
      // Redirect to a success page or send a response indicating success
      res.send("Friend request sent successfully!");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // Handle the error appropriately
      res.status(500).send("Error sending friend request");
    });
  console.log(sender);
  console.log(receiver);
});
```

When I `console.log` the `sender` value I properly get my own id however the `receiver` id is showing up as undefined which isn't allowing me to properly send the friend request.